# python help listing values in nested for loop

Tags: python, list, variables

How do I access the values in my second list (val)?

```
colors = [('teal','30a8a0'),('pink','b33b96'),('red','de3249'),('green','758f3d'),('purple','532c86'),('darkblue','116da4'),('skyblue','1d9dc5')]
darkblue=[('first'),('second')]

for (color,value) in colors:
    print color #teal, pink, red, etc...
    for (val) in {color}:
        print val #first, second, etc...
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, first you want to get the color from the variable colors, and then iterate over the list assigned to a variable with the same name as the said color?

Comment: it's not clear what you want to do, please explain what is your desired output

Comment: Also, I think you are using the wrong data-structures. You should use a dictionary, not a list of tuples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
subcolors = {'darkblue': ['first', 'second'],
             'teal': ['first-teal', 'second-teal'],
             'pink': ['first-pink', 'second-pink'],
             # etc..
            }

for (color,value) in colors:
    print color #teal, pink, red, etc...
    for val in subcolors[color]:
        print val #first-teal, second-teal, first-pink, second-pink, etc...
```

By putting the colors into a dict, we can retrieve them more easily and iterate through their values.

---

If you really want to do it from the `darkblue` variable and you don't want to use a dict, you can do this, but I wouldn't recommend it:

```
darkblue = ['first', 'second']
teal = ['first-teal', 'second-teal']
pink = ['first-pink', 'second-pink']
# etc...

for (color,value) in colors:
    print color #teal, pink, red, etc...
    for val in locals()[color]:
        print val #first-teal, second-teal, first-pink, second-pink, etc...
```

Comment: Thanks dhg, this is a better structure. This worked, but I had to unquote this: for (val) in subcolors[color]: